# Как записать список, содержащий списки, в виде таблицы в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я считал файл и получил список, который содержит информацию подобного вида

```
temp = []
file = open('example.txt', 'r')
for line in file.read().split('\n'):
    temp.append(line)

file.close()

lst = []
for i in temp:
    a = i.split()
    lst.append(a)
    a.append(int(a[1])*int(a[2]))
```

получил lst =

```
[['samsung', '50', '100', 5000], ['apple', '3', '20', 60]]
```

как мне правильно записать все в новый текстовый файл, чтобы получить

```
samsung          50         100           (50*100)
apple            3          20            (3*20)
```

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема? С перемножением? С записью в файл? С чем-то другим?

Comment: с записью в файл

Comment: Вы можете привести пример исходного файла?

Comment: related: [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение вашей задачи:

```
lines = open('example.txt', 'r').readlines()
f_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    tmp = line.split()
    s = int(tmp[1])*int(tmp[2])
    f_out.write("{0:<15}{1:<6}{2:<6}{3:<6}\n".format(*tmp, s))
```

Для вывода "таблиц" удобно использовать метод format. Советую [почитать про него](https://pyformat.info).

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать [модуль csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) из стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: а в нем есть табличный вывод в текстовый файл? Я не встречал. Если укажете ссылку на метод, буду благодарен)

Comment: `'{:15}{:6}{:6}{}'.format(*tmp, s)` - то же самое, но букв меньше (как питон "любит")

Comment: спасибо, адаптировав ваш код, все получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Для задач подобного рода идеально подходит [модуль Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Пример исходного файла (`'C:\Temp\1.txt'`):

```
samsung     50      100
apple       3       20
```

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r'C:\Temp\1.txt'

(pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['name','val1','val2'])
   .eval("val3 = val1*val2", inplace=False)
   .to_csv(r'c:/temp/out.txt', header=None, index=False, sep='\t')
)
```

Результат (`'C:\Temp\out.txt'`):

```
samsung 50  100 5000
apple   3   20  60
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# [['samsung', '50', '100'], ['apple', '3', '20']]
lst = list(map(str.split, filter(bool, map(str.strip, open('example.txt')))))

# [['samsung', '50', '100', '(50*100)=5000'], ['apple', '3', '20', '(3*20)=60']]
lst = [ls + ['({})={}'.format('*'.join(ls[1:]), (int(ls[1]) * int(ls[2])))] for ls in lst]

# {:>7} {:>2}   {:>3}   {:>13}
s = ' | '.join('{:<%s}' % max(len(lst[i1][i2]) for i1 in range(len(lst))) for i2 in range(len(lst[0])))

# samsung | 50 | 100 | (50*100)=5000
# apple   | 3  | 20  | (3*20)=60
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(s.format(*ls) for ls in lst))
```